# Sending many dynamically-generated emails with php

Tags: php, ajax, email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I have a script: `invoice.php?id=12` that generates an invoice in pdf and emails it to a customer with id = `$_GET['id']`.

Now, after sales are closed, Id like to send an email to all customers at once and I have no idea how to do that.

Generating one pdf and sending it by email takes about 3-4 seconds and there will be hundreds or even thousands of customers.

I'm using SwiftMailer PHP library, if that's relevant.

Any idea how I could do it?
Is there a way to loop through ajax requests for several hours?
Or is there a simpler solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are initiating an AJAX request for every email you would like to send. It would be a lot more efficient to send 1 email addressed to a lot of people, by specifying multiple receivers in the mail header as follows:

```
$email_to = "first@email.com,some@other.com,yet@another.net";
```

For SwiftMailer try this:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
    ->setFrom(array('your@mail.com' => 'John Doe'))
    ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'Name'))
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
;
```

Comment: It would be more efficient, but sadly not possible: the pdf invoice is different for every customer. Is there a way to send ajax requests one after another indefinitely?

Comment: Hmmm... can't help you with that, sorry.